# PySpark UDF to multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

So I have an UDF like this:

```
 tudf = udf(lambda value: 1 if value>=1 else 0,IntegerType())
```

And I normally just pass UDFs like this:

```
 df = fdf.withColumn('COLUMN1',tudf(df.COLUMN1))
```

I was wondering if there was any way to do this but with multiple columns without having to go one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use comprehension:

```
fdf.select([
  tudf(c).alias(c) if c in cols_to_transform else c for c in fdf.columns
])
```

although `udf` is not recommended here

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

fdf.select([
  when(col(c) >= 1, 1).otherwise(0).alias(c) if c in cols_to_transform else c 
  for c in fdf.columns
])
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Is it not recommended because it's heavier computationally?